# Update sensitivity label to M365 Group with Graph API and PowerShell throws 401 error

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, office365

UGH!

I'm struggling with 401 error when trying to update M365 groups sensitivity label information with Graph API and PowerShell. With Graph Explorer the beast works just fine, but with PowerShell I receive an error *Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.* -message. Updating groups description and displayname programatically works without exceptions. Azure app registration is consented with application level grants: Group.ReadWrite.All and Directory.ReadWrite.All as mentioned in the MS documentation. Any ideas?

Code sample:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $tenantBaseUrl -ClientId $clientId -Tenant $tenantId -Thumbprint $thumbPrint
$body=@"
{
    "assignedLabels": [
      {
        "labelId": "$labelId"  
      }
    ]
  }
"@
$AccessToken = (Get-PnPGraphAccessToken)
$headers = @{ Authorization=("Bearer " + $AccessToken)}
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/$groupId"
$webRequest = Invoke-RestMethod –Uri $uri -Body $body –Method Patch -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json"
```

Reference to MS-documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-2-apply-sensitivity-label-to-a-microsoft-365-group

Comment: Check the access token in https://jwt.ms if you have the required permissions or not?

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: Noup, I checked the token and it seems to be alright.

Comment: Hi, not working with PowerShell. The only difference between PowerShell and Graph Explorer is that the Graph Explorer uses additional delegated Directory.AccessAsUser.All -permission. @ShivaKeshavVarma

Comment: Do you have Directory.ReadWrite.All permission?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft Graph -> Directory.ReadWrite.All and Group.ReadWrite.All permissions added and consented to the app. @ShivaKeshavVarma

Comment: Are you a Global Admin?

Comment: Yes @ShivaKeshavVarma

Comment: It seems that app-only permission is not supported. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/issues/132 @ShivaKeshavVarma

Comment: Yes, looks like. Glad to know that :)

Comment: Yep, case "closed" :) @ShivaKeshavVarma

Answer (score 2):

It seems that app-only permission is not supported.

[Setting of sensitivity labels is not available with app credentials](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/issues/132)

Answer (score 0):

Token is valid. If I run the same command with same token, but only changing the body to update description and displayname it works.

```
$body2 = @"
{
    "description": "M365 Group new desc",
    "displayName": "M365 Group new displayname"
}
"@

$webRequest2 = Invoke-RestMethod –Uri $uri -Body $body2 –Method Patch -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json"
```