# Microsoft Graph API deprecation headers - how to interpret?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm calling an Microsoft Graph API endpoint to change sensitivity labels (like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67231463/update-sensitivity-label-to-m365-group-with-graph-api-and-powershell-throws-401) and documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-2-apply-sensitivity-label-to-a-microsoft-365-group)). It's a `beta` endpoint and currently working well. Here's how to use it according to the documentation:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "assignedLabels": 
  [
    {
        "labelId" : "45cd0c48-c540-4358-ad79-a3658cdc5b88"
    }
  ]
}
```

Looking at the response headers I noticed those three related to deprecation `Deprecation`, `Sunset` and `Link`:

```
  "Link": "<https://developer.microsoft-tst.com/en-us/graph/changes?$filterby=beta,PrivatePreview:Restricted_AU_Properties&from=2021-04-01&to=2021-05-01>;rel=\"deprecation\";type=\"text/html\",<https://developer.microsoft-tst.com/en-us/graph/changes?$filterby=beta,Device_Properties&from=2022-01-01&to=2022-02-01>;rel=\"deprecation\";type=\"text/html\"",
  "Deprecation": "Mon, 05 Apr 2021 23:59:59 GMT",
  "Sunset": "Sat, 19 Feb 2022 23:59:59 GMT",
```

I'm trying to determine whether this means that the endpoint stops working on Feb 19 with respect to *sensitivity labels*. The links in the `Link` response header unfortunately do not work and look kind of internal-ish. E.g. https://developer.microsoft-tst.com/en-us/graph/changes?$filterby=beta,PrivatePreview:Restricted_AU_Properties&from=2021-04-01&to=2021-05-01

Looking at the query parameters of the link I see the keywords `Restricted_AU_Properties` and `Device_Properties`. The [Microsoft Graph change log](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog/?filterBy=&search=assignedlabels) does not show anything about those or the `assignedLabels` that is about to happen.

How do I have to read this response? Is setting sensitivity labels using this endpoint going to stop working on Feb 19?

Answer (score 0):

Talking to a colleague helps. Apparently the `1.0` Graph API endpoint also allows setting sensitivity labels and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-v1.0#properties) claiming that it is **read-only** is **wrong**:

[image]

So my interpretation for now is that the deprecation headers tell me to use the `1.0` endpoint instead of `beta`. Which would *kind of* make sense.