# Is there a workaround for automatically assigning a sensitivity label to a Microsoft 365 group?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67231463/update-sensitivity-label-to-m365-group-with-graph-api-and-powershell-throws-401) question, Microsoft Graph doesn't allow you to use app-only permissions to assign a sensitivity label to a Microsoft 365 group.

Is there any workaround to automate the assignment of sensitivity labels with delegate permissions? I understand that any workaround will have drawbacks.

I have posted a suggestion [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/allow-sensitivity-labels-to-be-assigned-to-groups-using/idi-p/3609078) to request that Microsoft support app-only permissions for this operation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the document here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-2-apply-sensitivity-label-to-a-microsoft-365-group, i think the API is still in beta version not available in V1.0, As you have already raised a feature request, let's wait for it to be implemented.

I have upvoted for the request